# Program for printing all numbers that user inputs till 42 in Clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure

As the name suggests it is a very simple program to print numbers to screen till user inputs 42.

```
(map 
  println 
  (take-while 
    #(not= % "42") 
    (repeatedly #(.readLine *in*))))
```

I have started learning Clojure so please share whether there is some easier way to read lines or anything else that can be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a few things worth pointing out:

**Lazy sequences and side effects**

First and foremost, you should be careful about mixing side effects (printing using `println`) and lazy sequences (such as `map`, `repeatedly`, and many more). It may not work the way you expect. Here's an example of side effects just disappearing:

```
(let [lazy-effects (map println [1 2 3])]
  1)
```

This doesn't print anything as `lazy-effects` is never evaluated. There's no need to traverse the lazy sequence, and hence no need to evaluate `println` on each of the elements. To be sure, your code doesn't suffer from this, as you're evaluating `map` right in the REPL (or where ever else you're running it), but as soon as you put it inside `def` or any number of other hidden dangers, it'll no longer get evaluated. Just something to keep in mind.

**Using `doseq` and friends for forcing side effects**

With the above in mind, your code would work equally well, but not carry the hidden risk of postponing side effects inside a lazy sequence, if it made use of `doseq` or some of the other `do`-like constructs in Clojure. [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) could be used as follows:

```
(doseq [input (take-while #(not= % "42") (repeatedly read-line))]
  (println input))
```

If you think this feels slightly less "Clojure-like" in nature, you're right! Side effects generally mix poorly with many of Clojure's core constructs, and special care often needs to be taken. `doseq`, `doall` and a few other are provided to help in the case where you really want to force the evaluation of something.

**Using `read-line` from Clojure core**

As you probably noticed I managed to sneak in a reference to [read-line](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-line) above, which you might as well be using for this scenario. There is no inherent benefit except the removed need for Java interop.

Otherwise I'd say you're on the right track. The concept of generating an infinite lazy sequence using `repeatedly`, limiting its length using `take-while`, and transforming it using `map` is spot on. It just so happens that this works more painlessly with pure functions that do not cause side effects.

Comment: So basically I need to remember that lazy things are lazy till it's actually used somewhere. Right? There isn't anything specific to Clojure here just related to lazy evaluation. Correct?

Comment: Correct. This is general advice about lazy evaluation and side effects, and the relation to Clojure is only that Clojure core makes extensive use of lazy sequences.